# How do I solve/handle an occasional API 400 error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple script that makes calls to 8 different APIs every 30 minutes.  Just one of these APIs returns a 400 bad request error about once every couple of days, which seems a little odd.  Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, or perhaps a simple way to retry the call on failure if it's not my fault?

```
var hayurl = "https://api.naturalresources.wales/riverlevels/v1/all?Location=4016";

var hayheaders = {
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers": {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
};

var hayresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(hayurl, hayheaders);
```

Most of the time it simply returns the data I want but the occasional fails have me stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the correct response code is, then [mute HTTP exceptions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) and check for it using [`HTTPResponse.getResponseCode()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode()). In the example below, I assume the correct response code is 200.

```
function getApiData() {
  var url = "https://api.naturalresources.wales/riverlevels/v1/all?Location=4016";
  var params = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"},
    "muteHttpExceptions": true // Without this, you'll still get an error
  };
  var maximumAttempts = 5; // Set a limit of retry attempts to prevent an infinite loop
  var attemptCount = 0;
  do { // Execute this block
    attemptCount++; // This needs to be BEFORE the request in case of failure, otherwise it will never increment
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  } while (response.getResponseCode() != 200 && attemptCount < maximumAttempts); // If not 200, execute the block again
  return response;
}
```

Alternatively, use a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement. If you use this method, you neither need to mute HTTP exceptions nor know the exact successful response code. By disabling `muteHttpExceptions` (it is disabled by default), the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call will throw the error that you have been seeing. We're counting on this happening, because the error will be caught and then trigger the retry attempt. This may be a preferable strategy because it would catch other errors, whereas my first approach only catches the very specific instance where the response code is not exactly 200.

```
function getApiData() {
  var url = "https://api.naturalresources.wales/riverlevels/v1/all?Location=4016";
  var params = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
  };
  var maximumAttempts = 5; // Set a limit of retry attempts to prevent an infinite loop
  var attemptCount = 0;
  do { // Execute this block
    var isErrored = false; // Reset to false at the start of each new iteration
    try {
      attemptCount++; // This needs to be BEFORE the request in case of failure, otherwise it will never increment
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    } catch (err) {
      isErrored = true; // If there was an error, set to true so the script will try again
    }
  } while (isErrored && attemptCount < maximumAttempts); // If isErrored, execute the block again
  return response;
}
```

Just in case your not familiar the looping logic, I'm using a [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) statement, which will execute a block of code *first* and then check a condition to see if that code should continue to be executed.

Comment: This is excellent.  Thanks very much.  Version 2 is best since the api returns values for several variables.  Whilst the format of the data is predictable the actual value is not.  Does the use of try/catch/while replace the use of finally ie try/catch/finally?  Is there a protocol/best practice for when to use finally as opposed to just continuing with the code?

Comment: Great. Please consider marking the answer as accepted. The `do...while` statement does not replace a `finally` block. Note that `do...while` encompasses the entire `try...catch`, conversely `finally` would be a single, final step. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2154-i-finally-understand-the-finally-part-of-a-try-catch-control-statement.htm